# Linear regression model in distress inventory

Tags: machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to analyze the problem of vacant seat in a multiplex and build a machine learning model which gives a forecast of how many seats will remain vacant on a given day.
Should linear regression model be perfect here ?

Comment: If you visually inspect scatterplots of all variables vs. vacant seats, and you see clear and obvious indication that there is a linear relationship in each plot, then linear regression should be a useful analysis tool - if - you have all necessary variables quantified for analysis.

Comment: I am using day of week, movie rating, price as the variables, is there anything else you think should be there

Comment: I would not go to the theater if it were raining, so maybe some indication of local weather conditions?

Comment: Is there any reference or document which you can share on where to start coding

Comment: I think you can use most spreadsheets for multiple linear regression, and you should easily find tutorials for multiple linear regression is your choice of programming languages, See the answer to this question posted below for more suggestions on modeling methods. I do not know if linear regression is good here - that is the reason for my scatterplot suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Generally you never know what algorithm will provide you the best result. Therefore, try to implement most of them and compare their performance.

Linear regression is usually the simplest algorithm. So try other algorithms as well. Ensemble methods often produce best results.

Choose an evaluation criteria such as MSE or RMSE and check which algorithm gives the least value of RMSE.

Also, try implementing cross validation to keep a check on your model's performance.